# Enable print Background colors and images option in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am using window.print() to print the page in jquery. But when am printing the background colors and images are not applying in the print window popup until i check the option is Background color and images for browser print settings.

Is there any way to do handle this from jQuery (by implementing the code) by default?.

Comment: You can not override it with JavaScript/jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

First `window.print()` is native javascript and not jquery.

Second you cannot override browser's implementation or its settings unless otherwise you create some extensions for a browser.

You can do some things like allowing what to be printed and what not to be by css.

```
@media print {
   body{
     /* Here you can define print styles  */
   }
}
```

Comment: downvoter, care to elaborate?

Comment: media print is NOT going to make the background colors/images to appear.

Comment: @epascarello, when did I even say that???. I said some things can be controlled of what's to print and what not to